# A question about Rudin's proof of Lusin's theorem

Tags: real-analysis

In page 56 of Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*, it's stated:

> [I]f $f$ is a complex measurable function and $B_n=\{x:|f(x)|>n\}$, then $\bigcap B_n= \varnothing$.

My question is why?

Comment: Roughly, $\bigcap_n B_n$ is the set where $|f|=+\infty$.

Comment: Because $f$ is assumed to be defined everywhere. It's absolute value cannot attain infinity.

Comment: By a complex measurable function $ f $, we mean that $ f: X\to\mathbb C $. And $ \mathbb C $ is the set of all the complex numbers.

Answer (score 4):

By definition, a complex function is a map $X\to\Bbb C$. If $f$ is complex, then the set $\bigcap B_n$ is the set of all points $x$ such that $|f(x)| > n$ for every $n\in\Bbb N$. There is no complex number $z$ with the property that $|z|>n$ for every natural number $n$. Hence there is no such $x\in\bigcap B_n$, so $\bigcap B_n = \varnothing$.